# Saving dates in Angular 2 and JSON

Tags: json, date, angular

This has been a very difficult problem I have run into with my Angular 2 app. I am trying to format my API (MongoDB) so that each new "post" added by the admin can be fetched by the DATE (not time) by the front end. For example, my schema looks like this:

```
    {name: "The best product ever",date: "25092016",quantity: 345},{name:"The okayest product ever",date: "26092016",quantity: 544,}
```

As you can tell, the date property is a single number. I then have a function that fetches the data from the object with the current date. However, this is the problem. The date format I am using for the JSON is 'ddMMyyyy'. This worked well for the date pipe in the HTML template, but I cannot seem to be able to format any date in a variable to match this format, or a similar format. All the dates in Angular 2 classes show GMT and timestamps, etc.

How to I format a date in Angular 2 components to match a short succinct string format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that `DatePipe` even in your code. :)

https://plnkr.co/edit/6pbHMVSTmndvs9CqYYUL?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    let dp = new DatePipe('de-DE' /* locale .. */);
    this.name = dp.transform(new Date(), 'ddMMyyyy');
    console.log(name);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or you want to use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)..

Comment: I was not aware you could use that in your code too! Thanks so much